# JSRuntime Error when splitting Blazorise LineChart code into a Razor Component

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazorise

I originally had a working [Blazorise](https://github.com/stsrki/Blazorise) LineChart which simply pulls a company's stock price data from the last week and puts it into a simple Line Chart.

I wanted to refactor this Page to split the code for the LineChart into a Razor Component with a Partial Class to allow me to reuse this Component, add other similar Components and to clean up my code.

After doing this following the MSDN documenation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#partial-class-support) (and without making any functionality changes) I then get the following JSRuntime error in my console and therefore the LineChart no longer displays:

[image]

Below are the relevant snippets of code for my Razor Component - could anyone please give me some advice as to why this error is showing?

**Index.Razor**

```
@page "/"
@using Stock_Market_Dashboard.Components

<LineChartComponentBase />
```

Below files located in located in **Project/Components**:

**_Imports.Razor**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using Blazorise
@using Blazorise.Charts
```

**LineChartComponent.razor**

```
@inherits LineChartComponentBase

<Card>
    <CardHeader>Settings</CardHeader>
    <CardBody>
        <Paragraph Visibility="Visibility.Always" Style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;margin:auto;">
            <Switch Style="padding-right: 20px;" TValue="bool" Checked="@amazon" CheckedChanged="@OnAmazonChanged">Amazon</Switch>
            <Switch Style="padding-right: 20px;" TValue="bool" Checked="@apple" CheckedChanged="@OnAppleChanged">Apple</Switch>
            <Switch TValue="bool" Checked="@google" CheckedChanged="@OnGoogleChanged">Google</Switch>

            <Button Style="margin-left:20px;padding:0;font-weight:bolder;" Clicked="@(async () => await HandleRedraw(lineChart))">Refresh</Button>
    </Paragraph>

    </CardBody>
</Card>

<LineChart @ref="lineChart" TItem="DataPoint" OptionsObject="@lineChartOptions" />
```

**LineChartComponent.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Stock_Market_Dashboard.Data;
using Extensions;
using Blazorise.Charts;

namespace Stock_Market_Dashboard.Components
{
    public partial class LineChartComponentBase : ComponentBase
    {
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instantly after posting this question I realised my mistake, I was referencing the Base class in my **Index.Razor** instead of the LineChartComponent itself - rookie error! My code now works :-)